# Get a single value from a nested associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

For a setup script I write in PHP (for CLI, not web) I use a settings file as well as other other "content" files.

The settings file is built up like a regular ini-file

```
[header.subheader.moreheaders...]
keyA = value
keyB = value1|value2|...
```

"header.subheader.moreheaders..." and "keyX" will form a nested associative array with "value" as a string or "value1|value2|..." as a simple array (0-...).

Thanks to [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541950/2513512), I got so far that I can split the headers into a recursive array recursively.  So far, so good.

However, as the content files shall contain references to these variables, I would like to be able to read out single values from that multi-dimensional array with string placeholders like `$@R[header.subheader.moreheaders.key]` or `$@R[header.subheader.moreheaders.key.0]` depending on them being a string or an array.

In the script, `$@R[header.subheader.moreheaders.key.0]` should convert into `$SettingsVar[header][subheader][moreheaders][key][0]` to return the appropriate value.

Neither the script nor the content files will know what is inside the settings file.  The script just knows the general structure and placeholder `$@R[...]`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27152184/2513512) appears to know what value will be in order to search for it.

Since I do not fully understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47309270/2513512), I am not sure if that would be the right way.

Is there a similar easy way to get the reverse from [building that array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541950/2513512)?

Comment: you might want to look at parse_ini_file http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: The building of the array from my settings file is already done and works like "parse_ini_file" on overdrive with even subsections already included.  My question is on how do I get a specific value out again when the script does not know what could be defined.  Maybe simpler: How do I convert `"a.b.c.d"` to `$var["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"]` in order to get the value stored there.

Comment: php variable cannot start $@

Comment: That is correct.  In fact, this is no variable in any script language or configuration file placeholder I know of, which makes using this with str_replace(“$@R”, $some_var) outstanding to read in and convert what is inside `[...]` following it using the script.  Then all I need to do is convert `”a.b.c.d”`, so I can use it with the internal script variable (example: $var[“a”][“b”][“c”][“d”]) to read out the value in there to replace the placeholder in the line of the contents file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some contemplation, I found a decent enough solution, which works for me (and hopefully others):

```
function GetNestedValue($aNestedKeys, $aNestedArray)
{
    $vValue = $aNestedArray;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($aNestedKeys); $i++)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($aNestedKeys[$i], $vValue))
        {
            $vValue = $vValue[$aNestedKeys[$i]];
        }
        else
        {
            $vValue = null;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $vValue;
}
```

Depending on what `$aNestedKeys` contain, it will either return a sub-array from `$aNestedArray`, a single value from it or `null` if any of the specified keys were not found.